# Where do I define @font-face in shopify?

Tags: schema, shopify, product, font-face

I upload some font-related files in assets in Shopify. But I don't know where and how to define the below code.

```html
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FreeSansBold';
    src: url('FreeSansBold.eot');
    src: url('FreeSansBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('FreeSansBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('FreeSansBold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('FreeSansBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('FreeSansBold.svg#FreeSansBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: what theme are you using?

Answer (score 2):

using `url_filters`, fonts were still not loading. So I did few things,

uploaded all the fonts in settings > Files

copied the link of the asset
then I add the below code in my style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "xyz";
    src: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/xxxx/xxxx/files/xyz.otf?v=1662111595') format("opentype");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a `css` file call `custom-fonts.css` or anything you like

add the `@font-face` code you have and declare `font-family` to the tag

go to `theme.liquid`

find your `theme.scss.css` or `theme.css` line and
put this line after

```
{{'custom-fonts.css' | asset_url | styplesheet_tag}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new file and increasing the https count you can directly include the code in theme.css file of your theme

Answer (score 0):

To reference the font files you need to use the `asset_url` [url filter](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/url-filters#asset_url). You do that by passing the file name to the filter, as below.

eg.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FreeSansBold';
    src: url("{{ 'FreeSansBold.eot' | asset_url }}");
    // ... repeat for other urls
}
```

Please note, this will only work in a file that ends `.liquid`, eg `theme.liquid` or `fonts.css.liquid`.